# Spurious targets when installing a software with CMake

Tags: cmake

I wrote a software whose configuration, building and installation are performed by means of some CMake files. This software is developped in a continuous integration process based on unit and functional tests. I noticed that targets corresponding to these tests are built during the installation step. It is not necessary at all and I would like to understand how to prevent CMake from doing it.

After having typed

```
make install
```

I get the following output:

> [  7%] Built target arpack
>
> [ 15%] Built target boost
>
> [ 23%] Built target eigen
>
> [ 31%] Built target yamlcpp
>
> [ 34%] Built target simol-core
>
> [ 36%] Built target simol-quantchem
>
> [ 80%] Built target simol-statphys
>
> [ 88%] Built target gtest
>
> [ 91%] Built target simol_test_unit
>
> [ 92%] Built target simol_test_functional
>
> [ 93%] Built target test_bichainfpu
>
> [ 94%] Built target test_dpde
>
> [ 95%] Built target test_fluid
>
> [ 96%] Built target test_galerkin
>
> [ 97%] Built target test_hamiltonian
>
> [ 98%] Built target test_langevin
>
> [ 99%] Built target test_rotor
>
> [100%] Built target test_trichain

The steps from 88% to 100% are definitively spurious since I do not install any tests but only the core of the software and its modules. For example, the CMake command which installs simol-statphys (80%) is

```
INSTALL(TARGETS simol-statphys ARCHIVE DESTINATION lib)
```

I have a similar command for simol-core (34%) and simol-quantchem (36%). I can understand why previous targets are built (arpack, boost, eigen, yamlcpp) because the modules of the software depend on these external libraries. But they do not depend on the tests. The reverse is true: tests obviously depend on the module. But it does not make sense to me why they should be involved in the installation step. Of course, there is no call to the INSTALL command for the tests. These tests are only defined like this:

```
ADD_EXECUTABLE(test_galerkin ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/test/functional/statphys/galerkin/TestGalerkin.cpp) 
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(test_galerkin simol-statphys)
```

Does anybody know what is happening here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CMake **doesn't track dependency** between **installed** targets and their **built** counterpairs. Instead, whole *install* (pseudo-)target is made dependent from *all* one.

So, whatever is built during `make all` is built also on `make install`.

If you don't want to build tests on `make install`, exclude them from `make all`. The simplest way to do this is using option *EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL* in `add_executable()` invocation:

```
ADD_EXECUTABLE(test_galerkin EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL ...)
```